# Android Action Bar and the I/O project

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was reading [Using the Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and it says, "... if you want to use Action Bar APIs, such as to add tabs or modify Action Bar styles, you need to set the android:minSdkVersion to '11', so you can access the ActionBar class."  But, in the [I/O](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) project, the Manifest has '7' as the minSdkVersion.  How are they able to do the themes and tabs?  I'm having trouble following what they're doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the important code to look at is in [ActivityHelper](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/ActivityHelper.java) and [ActivityHelperHoneycomb](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/ActivityHelperHoneycomb.java).  Basically they're setting `android:targetSdkVersion="11"` and `android:minSdkVersion="7"`, then selectively calling the new ActionBar APIs on Honeycomb (or higher) and their own custom action bar implementation pre-Honeycomb.

If you don't already have action bar code for pre-Honeycomb, there's a nice project called [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) which allows you to simply use the ActionBar API and have it work on pre-Honeycomb (just change some imports).

**NOTE:** If you decide to use ActionBarSherlock and you've upgraded your environment to use the newly released API level 13r1 or 12r2 code make sure to use version 3.0.3 or higher (more info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/gdD6UdZ1qGU)).

**EDIT:** A little more background to better answer your question.  Setting `android:targetSdkVersion="11"` is enough to give you access to the `ActionBar` class.  Setting `android:targetSdkVersion="7"` allows the app to run on pre-honeycomb devices, but calling `ActionBar` code from them would result in a `NoClassDefFoundError` (or maybe `NoSuchMethodError`?).

To avoid that, they're using `ActivityHelper` for API levels < 11 and `ActivityHelperHoneycomb` on API levels >= 11. [ActivityHelper#createInstance(Activity)](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/ActivityHelper.java#45) is where they decide which to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for my delay. I figured out much of that. It appears that there is no menu overflow for the non-honeycomb actionbar. The I/O app only ever has 3 menu items at most as far as I can tell. And the menu button is disabled for the entire app. Am I missing overflow somewhere? I wonder how to handle more than 3 menu items. I'd hate to have to enable the menu for phones...